# Editing the footer menu label in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit the footer menu text not the sub menu in wordpress.
e.g. if footer menu has menu like -

Product
 - prod1

  - prod2

I want to change the "Product" text not prod1 or prod2.
When I try to edit menus in wordpress it gives me the list of menus in dropdown but does not give any provision to edit the menu label. can anyone please suggest the solution.

Thanks

Comment: That text may be specific to your theme. It could be in an options panel somewhere or it might be hard coded. But either way, this is not an appropriate forum for theme support.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the "Navigation Label". Just click the caret on each navigation item that you'd like to change, and you'll see the Navigation Label field there.

[image: Navigation Label]

Comment: thanks for a quick response.. I wanted to change the menu name - "Footer Menu" (here) .. but somehow label in text that is appearing on frontend is different. Do we add alias somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you might need to look at the footer.php template in your theme. WordPress menus don't usually display the Menu Name on the frontend by default.

Comment: Ok sorry.. got the solution.. footer menu names were hard coded in my theme files.. bones.php ... thanks for your response again